# JavaScript: How to find out the position of the mouse in the div box?

Tags: javascript

I know how to find out the position of the mouse relative to the top-left corner of the browser window, but I don't know how to do so relative to the top-left corner of the div box.

Comment: Which framework are you using? (I hope you're using one).

Mootools uses `Element.getPosition()`
jQuery uses `jQuery.posistion()`

Answer (score 1):

Try the follow Javascript function.

```
var IE = document.all?true:false

if (!IE) {
 document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
}



function getMousePosition(e) {
  if (IE) { 
    var X = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft
    var Y = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
  } else { 
    var X = e.pageX
    var Y = e.pageY
  }  

  if (X < 0) {
       X = 0
   }
  if (Y < 0) {
     Y = 0
  }  
  alert("X : "+ X +" Y: "+ Y);
}

document.onmousemove = getMousePosition;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get the top-left corner of the div box, you can just subtract this from the screen coordinates of the mouse.

Comment: Of course, I would do so myself, but the problem is how to get the coordinates without relying on the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [page](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#position), there are 6 pairs of coordinate. You may try them. I guess the right one might be `clientX,clientY`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Those are relative to the entire computer screen of the user.